# How to remove intelacing effects from videos with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, interlacing

I have some old interlaced video-files but you will not believe that 
I have not any more CRT Tv and that videos looks very bad on my PC.

I would like to re-encode them with ffmpeg avoiding such double-image effect, 
as you can see in this picture:

https://www.settebello.info/var/interlaced.php

I tried various yadif mode but all of them seam opposite to my needs.

The current video size is 720x416, I could accept a video scaled down to 360x208
but without this mix-frames effects.

**Ffmpeg stream Info:**

Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg4 (DX50 / 0x30355844), yuv420p, 720x416 [SAR 1:1 DAR 45:26], 886 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 30k tbc

These are some of my last efforts:

```sh
ffmpeg -i movie.avi -ss 120 -t 30 -vf "yadif=0, scale=360x208" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19  -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.mp4

ffmpeg -i movie.avi -ss 120 -t 30 -vf "yadif=1, scale=360x208" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19  -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.mp4

ffmpeg -i movie.avi -ss 120 -t 30 -vf "yadif=2, scale=360x208" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 19  -c:a aac -b:a 256k output.mp4
```

Please help.

Comment: I've used bwdif rather than yadif in the past and had okay results eg `ffmpeg -i "input_video.avi" -vf "bwdif" -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 18 -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -b:a 256k "output_video.mp4" ` but it did depend on source material

Comment: Nope this did not work, I still obtain same mixed frames output...